# python pandas: DataFrame of DataFrames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I inherited a pandas DataFrame of pandas Series.

For example:

```
 hf = pd.DataFrame([
    [pd.Series(np.random.random(4), index=['a', 'e', 'o', 'u'])
     for i in range(2)],
    [pd.Series(np.random.random(4), index=['a', 'e', 'o', 'u'])
     for i in range(2)]],
                  columns = ['col1', 'col2'],
                  index = ['row1', 'row2'])
```

Which gives a 2x2 pd.DataFrame, each cell containing a 4x1 pd.Series
such as for example:

`type(hf.loc['row1', 'col1'])` shows `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`
and

`hf.loc['row1', 'col1'].shape` shows: `(4,)`

**Question:**

Is there more elegant and efficient way to extract all the values of 'a' across all rows within one columns than using for example:

```
a_elements = [hf.loc[r, 'col1'].loc['a'] for r in hf.index]
```

thanks

On python 3.6, pandas 0.24.0

Comment: You are making a "3D" data frame via a really hacky way. Pandas is built for 1-D and 2-D problems, so there'll be no optimal solution for this using pandas IMO. You can always just do `hf.col1.str.get(0)` to get the first element from all series, but that's such a bad design that I would advise against.  You should consider working with numpy arrays and three axes instead of a 2-D pandas dataframe with iterables on the cells.